# Why tabulate command giving error of multiple values? How to make a table to compare values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert data in tabular form but it is giving me error that  "tabulate() got multiple values for argument 'headers". How can I fix this error? I tried to follow the example that was given in one of the questions posted on this site. I want to make a comparison between value-1 and value_2 just like in a table.

```
`print(tabulate([['Alice', 24], ['Bob', 19]], headers=['Name', 'Age']))

#Example-2
a= np.arange(5)
b=[10,12,14,16,18]
print(tabulate(a, b, headers=['value_1', 'values_2']))`
```

Comment: Looking at the source code for the tabulate method, the function is defined as `tabulate(tabular_data, headers=[], ...)`. In the final call, `b` is taken as the value for headers, and then you pass in a header named argument, thus the error. Source: https://github.com/gregbanks/python-tabulate/blob/master/tabulate.py

Comment: So how can I fix that error?

Comment: `tabulate([a, b], headers=...)`

Comment: I tried to encapsulate it in square backets but that is not the result that I want . I want to make a comparison between two values and I want to show them in a table

Comment: `a+b` then, obviously.

Comment: sorry But I'm not getting the required result

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` need to be part of a single list:

```
print(tabulate([a, b], headers=['value_1', 'values_2']))
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix there error merge array's `a` and `b`:

```
a= np.arange(5)
b=[10,12,14,16,18]
c = a.append(b)
print(tabulate(c, headers=['value_1', 'values_2']))
```

Comment: I copied the same code but it is not showing values in a table

Comment: Are any errors raised? 

Have you tried `print(tabulate([a, b], headers=['value_1', 'values_2']))` like @ibarrond suggested?

Comment: Yes I printed the same command. But that is not data in table form

Comment: It prints rows.I need values_1 in 1st column and values_2 in column 2.

Comment: I got some ideas for debugging like so: What if you print it with no headers? If that works, what about doing this instead `print aka headers=['value_1', 'values_2']` then do `print(tabulate(c, headers)`?  Also I doubt this matters but have you tried using double quotes instead of single quotes?

Also take a look at this documentation. Near the bottom are a few ideas you could possibly try out[Tabulate Documentation](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)

If all comes to worse you could use [Pretty Table](https://pypi.org/project/PrettyTable/)

Also what do you mean it prints rows?

Comment: ` 0   1   2   3   4
    10  12  14  16  18 ` I got output in this form . I want that 0 1 2 3 4 should be in fist column instead of row and  10 12 14 16 18 should be in second column instead of row